# How can I move the page number to the right side of toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

I've created this code to style the table of contents page

```
\contentsmargin{0cm}
 \titlecontents{part}[-1pc]
 {\addvspace{10pt}%
 \color{doc}\Large PART\quad}%
 {}
 {}
 {}%
 %------------------------------------------
 \titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
 {\addvspace{10pt}%
 \color{doc}\large\sc\bfseries}%
 {}
 {}
 {\;\;\normalsize\thecontentspage}%
 \titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
 {\addvspace{1pt}}
 {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
 {}
 {\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
 []
 \titlecontents*{subsection}[4pc]
 {\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
 {} 
 {}
 {\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
 [ \textbullet\ ][]

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
 \chapter*{%
 \vspace*{-20\p@}%
 \color{doc}\contentsname}%
 \@starttoc{toc}}
 \makeatother
```

And I want the page number to appear to the right side of the page.
Like this picture shows (without the dots):

[image]

Comment: Do you want the page numbers for the page(s) belonging to the Table of Contents to be placed top-right, middle-right (i.e., in the margin), or bottom-right? Separately, have you considered using the `tocloft` package to help design the look of the ToC? Please advise.

Comment: Do you want to imitate the overall look of the ToC shown in the image or just to move the page numbers for chapter entries to the right? If it's just the numbers, instead of `\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
 {\addvspace{10pt}
 \color{doc}\large\sc\bfseries}
 {}
 {}
 {\;\;\normalsize\thecontentspage}`
use `\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
 {\addvspace{10pt}
 \color{doc}\large\sc\bfseries}
 {}
 {}
 {\hfill\normalsize\thecontentspage}` (as a side note, your code as it is now will produce errors since you are using \; outside math mode.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the page numbers for chapter entries to the right, you can use `\hfill` before `\thecontentspage`:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
  {\addvspace{10pt}\color{doc}\large\scshape\bfseries}{}{}   
  {\hfill\normalsize\thecontentspage}
```

As a side note, your original code will produce errors since you are using `\;` outside math mode.